# It's good for puzzling

Tags: riddle, wordplay, visual

The images below can be connected by a single word.

[image: Fair ground (wordplay)]

[image: A horse trotting]

[image: The head of a Lego person]

[image: A collection of traditional games]

[image: A world map]

[image: A seriously cool hover craft]

What is the word and what are the connections?

Comment: That's a really nice puzzle!

Comment: @A.D.  I love these visual riddles.  They're relatively easy to put together to be honest but I do like both making and solving them.  And I'd never have seen one if not for puzzling SE.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is

> War

because

> 1. Fair → Warfare  
>  2. Horse → War horse 
>  3. Head → Warhead (chemical or nuclear) 
>  4. Games → War games 
>  5. World → World War I and II 
>  6. Hovercraft → Warcraft

and the title is referring to

> [Edwin Starr's hit record](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX7V6FAoTLc)

Comment: Oh nice, that's gotta be it

Comment: Well done +1.  Sorry for the late reply.  You got it.  Good explanations too.

Answer (score 9):

I think the word may be

> **TRADE**

Image connections are:

> 1. Fair → FAIR **TRADE**
>  2. Horse → HORSE **TRADE**
>  3. Interchangeable head → HEAD **TRADE**R or HEAD OF **TRADE**
>  4. Game boards → BOARD(S) OF **TRADE**
>  5. World map → WORLD **TRADE**
>  6. Hover craft → **TRADE**CRAFT

And the title:

> **TRADE** ←→ Stack **Exchange**

This seems to fit better than my prior attempt.

Comment: Good connections, some I'd never have thought of, but there's a better fit.  +1

Comment: I thought of one and was already typing it up when your comment arrived :)

Answer (score 7):

I think the word is:

> **OVER**

Here are some explanations:

> 1. Fair → the ferries wheel is a turning device, thus the word is **OVERTURN**
>  2. Horse → the horse is in running position, thus the word is **OVERRUN**,
>  3. Head → **OVERHEAD**,
>  4. Games → those are board games, thus the word is **OVERBOARD**,
>  5. Map → it's a view of the world, thus the word is **OVERVIEW**,
>  6. Hovercraft → it's a mean of transportation, thus the word is **OVERRIDE**.

Thanks to @Techidiot for new ideas.

Comment: *Turn over* / *Hang over* for 1st and *H+over* for last seems good.

Comment: Excellent connections

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of the accepted answer, but this is what first came to mind:

> Rotate

Because:

> 1. Ferris wheel's rotate
> 2. Horses can fall in a way called a "rotational fall".
> 3. Lego Movie had a whole plot point about those lego heads being good for rotation.
> 4. The games shown have turn rotations.
> 5. Earth rotates on its axis
> 6. Hovercrafts have a rotating fan.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

> Water

Reason:

> 1. Water park - Many theme parks are water parks or have a waterpark.
>  2. Water horse - Movie
>  3. Water head - source of a headstream.
>  4. Water board - board boardgames.  Water board a form of torture.
>  5. Earth - Has oceans/water?
>  6. Hovercraft - Can be used on water.

Comment: Some good connections +1

Answer (score 3):

I think it is:

> wooden.

Because

> wooden Funfair
>  Wooden horse
>  [Wooden-head](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woodenhead)
>  Wooden tabletop or board
>  Wooden globe
>  [Wooden hovercraft](https://www.wired.com/2012/05/ff_hovercraft/)

Comment: Some good connections +1

Answer (score 3):

I think

> PLAY

because

> Fair play (hah)
>  Horseplay
>  [A LEGO man's decapitated head!](https://youtu.be/omOZyLmNMJs?t=38) → ... brains ... ok, because LEGO means PLAY
>  Play the game ☺
>  A world map → RISK is played on a world map. Or the Globe theatre hosts plays
>  Cool hovercraft → Play it COOL

or possibly

> MEAT

because

> ground meat
>  horse meat
>  ... brains ...
>  game ... (venison, for example) is meat
>  that looks like a map showing worldwide consumption of meat
>  [it's full of eels](http://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/hovercraft.htm)

Comment: Presuming I can comment on my own answer ... should I split this into two answers?

Comment: Some good connections +1, and I think submitting as separate answers or one, as you've done here, is largely a matter of preference.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice